# Bad performance when offering files to download with HttpListener

Tags: c#, httplistener

I'm trying to create a simple web server using `HttpListener` in `C#` and offer files to download. I'm seeing really bad transfer rates especially compared to copying that same file from a share. Is this known to `HttpListener` and what can be done to improve it?

Here's some additional info about research I have done about the problem. Download rates improve a lot when connecting locally but copying the file is done almost instantly in this case, so it's hard to measure a difference ratio. When connecting remotely (`LAN` environment, machines right next to each other) however, the transfer time is roughly 25x the time of a simple file copy from a share. The available network bandwidth doesn't seem to be used to speed this up.

I've found some other questions and discussions about `HttpListener` that seem to indicate similar issues, see here:

[HttpListener vs native performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455887/httplistener-vs-native-http-performance)

[HttpListener Performance Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907841/httplistener-performance-optimization) (this is not regarding downloads however)

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229710.aspx) also state that `HttpListener` is based on `http.sys` which allows for bandwidth throttling. Could it be that some unwanted bandwidth throttling is going on here or is there something wrong with my code? On the machines I've tested with (Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2), no IIS was present.

In my sample, I'm starting an `HttpListener` like so:

```
  HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
  listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:80/");
  listener.Start();
```

Here's the code for my simple file download:

```
  HttpListenerResponse response = null;
  try {
      HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

      response = context.Response;

      using( FileStream fs = File.OpenRead( @"c:\downloadsample\testfile.pdf" ) ) {

          byte[] buffer = new byte[ 32768 ];
          int read;
          while( ( read = fs.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length ) ) > 0 ) {
              response.OutputStream.Write( buffer, 0, read );
          }
      }

  } finally {
      if( response != null )
          response.Close();
  }
```

(edit: fixed some links...)

Comment: You probably need to use async I/O to make this faster

Comment: What Steve means is that while you read the next chunk you can in the meantime already send the previously read chunk over the network. Currently you are 2 times blocked by IO. One time by reading from disc and the second time when you send it over the wire. It could be that you have a high GC time. Check with a profiler where most of the time is spent.

Comment: Steve and Alois, thanks for your comments. I had also tested with a C# client (HttpWebRequest) and had async I/O for writing the received data. To be honest I doubt that changing this will make it faster by an order of magnitude. I will (a) change it to async sending and (b) check with a profiler and try to find out what it's doing.

Comment: Answering myself, it all depends on the correct headers and especially the buffer size. In my LAN environment, I can get speeds close to a normal file copy using e.g. 1MB buffer size (1048576). I bet that your hint of using async I/O would speed things up even more. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

### Overall

The two tests that were run (C# HttpListener serving a file and an smb file copy test) contain too many variables to draw any useful conclusions about the performance of HttpListener vs. native code.

All other code in such cases should be suspect of causing the performance problem and should be removed from the test case.

Unfortunately, the question's implementation of serving a file is non-optimal as it reads a chunk from the file into a managed byte array, then blocks on a call to write that block to the kernel.  Its copying the bytes of the file into a managed array and back out of a managed array (adding no value in the process).  With .Net 4.5 you could have called CopyToAsync between the file stream and the output stream, which would get you out of the business of figuring out how to do that in parallel.

### Conclusions

The test below shows that HttpListener is just as fast at sending back bytes as IIS Express 8.0 returning a file.  For this post I tested this on a cheesy 802.11n network with the servers on a VM and still reached 100+ Mbps with both HttpListener and IIS Express.

The only thing that needs to be changed in the original post is how it reads the file to relay it back to the client.

If you want to serve files via HTTP you should probably use an existing web server that handles both the HTTP side of things and the file opening/caching/relaying.  You will find it hard to beat existing web servers, particularly when you bring gzipping dynamic responses into the picture (in that case the naive approach gzips the entire response, accidentally, before sending any of it, which wastes time that could have been used for sending bytes).

## Better Test to Isolate Just HttpListener's Performance

I created a test that returns a 10 MB string of integers (generated once on startup) to allow testing the speed at which HttpListener can return data when it's given the whole block up front (which is similar to what it could do when you use CopyToAsync).

## Test Setup

Client Computer: MacBook Air mid-2013, 1.7 GHz Core i7
Server Computer: iMac mid-2011, 3.4 GHz Core i7 - Windows 8.1 Hosted in VMWare Fusion 6.0, Bridged Networking
Network: 802.11n via Airport Extreme (located 8 feet away)
Download Client: curl on Mac OS X

## Test Results

IIS Express 8.0 was configured to serve an 18 MB file and the HttpListenerSpeed program was setup to return 10 MB and 100 MB responses.  The test results were essentially identical.

### IIS Express 8.0 Results

```
Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8000/TortoiseSVN-1.8.2.24708-x64-svn-1.8.3.msi > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  13.1M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.1M

Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8000/TortoiseSVN-1.8.2.24708-x64-svn-1.8.3.msi > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  13.0M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.1M

Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8000/TortoiseSVN-1.8.2.24708-x64-svn-1.8.3.msi > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  9688k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 9737k
```

### HttpListenerSpeed Results

```
Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8080/garbage > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  12.6M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.1M

Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8080/garbage > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  13.1M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.1M

Harolds-MacBook-Air:~ huntharo$ curl -L http://iMacWin81.local:8080/garbage > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.4M  100 18.4M    0     0  13.2M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.2M
```

## HttpListenerSpeed Code

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace HttpListenerSpeed
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listener = new Listener();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

            listener.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    internal class Listener
    {
        private const int RequestDispatchThreadCount = 4;
        private readonly HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Thread[] _requestThreads;
        private readonly byte[] _garbage;

        internal Listener()
        {
            _garbage = CreateGarbage();

            _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
            _httpListener.Start();
            _requestThreads = new Thread[RequestDispatchThreadCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < _requestThreads.Length; i++)
            {
                _requestThreads[i] = new Thread(RequestDispatchThread);
                _requestThreads[i].Start();
            }
        }

        private static byte[] CreateGarbage()
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[2150000];

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = 1000000 + i;
            }

            Shuffle(numbers);

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join<int>(", ", numbers));
        }

        private static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
            {
                // Pick random element to swap.
                int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
                // Swap.
                T tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }

        private void RequestDispatchThread()
        {
            while (_httpListener.IsListening)
            {
                string url = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    // Yeah, this blocks, but that's the whole point of this thread
                    // Note: the number of threads that are dispatching requets in no way limits the number of "open" requests that we can have
                    var context = _httpListener.GetContext();

                    // For this demo we only support GET
                    if (context.Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        context.Response.Close();
                    }

                    // Don't care what the URL is... you're getting a bunch of garbage, and you better like it!
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    context.Response.ContentLength64 = _garbage.Length;
                    context.Response.OutputStream.BeginWrite(_garbage, 0, _garbage.Length, result =>
                    {
                        context.Response.OutputStream.EndWrite(result);
                        context.Response.Close();
                    }, context);
                }
                catch (System.Net.HttpListenerException e)
                {
                    // Bail out - this happens on shutdown
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception: {0}", e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        internal void Shutdown()
        {
            if (!_httpListener.IsListening)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Stop the listener
            _httpListener.Stop();

            //  Wait for all the request threads to stop
            for (int i = 0; i < _requestThreads.Length; i++)
            {
                var thread = _requestThreads[i];
                if (thread != null) thread.Join();
                _requestThreads[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "// Note: the number of threads that are dispatching requets in no way limits the number of "open" requests that we can have". Sorry don't see that. Each thread is blocked until start writting, so only 4 requests can be handled simultaneous. In case all reqs takes longer to be generated, this will block new ones. Am i wrong? What about getting context async?

Comment: It does use the async pattern but it uses the older begin/end style so more people can use it. I can assure you that you can send way more than 4 requests at once and they will all get picked up. You'll see funny results if you run the test client and the test server on the same machine and you have less than 4 CPU cores.  You would ideally want to test that with 8 or more cores and two machines. Then you should see it pickup more than 4 requests at a time for sure.

Comment: Hi huntharo, I expected `BeginContext` to create a separate thread to process the request but from this http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html seems that's not true, so I'll follow your approach. Thanks.